# NullReferenceException when importing model

Tags: unity

This error most certainly is not caused by an error in my Script. I don't know where it came from, I don't know why it's here and I don't understand what problems it causes because everything seems to work just fine. But I've been getting this error for quite a while now every single time I run the Game Engine:

[image: Debug console showing error]

Comment: Have you tried to : close Unity, delete de Library and Temp folder, and open Unity again ?

Comment: Same issue ..First thing update your unity version to 5.6...and .im not sure why this error occur but it can be easily track by finding the culprit from your project . You need to make another separate unity project then move your code to new project and check the error still there and if not then start to move your models which has no animation and move them to new project and check that either any error still there now import all the model which has animation. And for me it works for just to update unity and restart the project.

Comment: @Hellium That seemed to work, the error is gone.

Comment: @figh8back I already have 5.6. Did the error cause you any problems?

Comment: No it's not that serious ....Did you restart unity ...And then check or otherwise make a clean project and import individual things.....but make sure model with animation import then at the end some times these also generate issue in import

Answer (score 1):

It's in ModelImporter. It's a problem with one of the 3d models you're using.

Comment: How do I figure out which one?

Comment: I'm not sure, my work in Unity is almost always 2d. :( I'd guess that you could make an empty project, and import all the models. If you get the same error, you know it's that. Then remove all the models and add them one by one until you get the error.

Comment: I have copied all the models in the Asset folder to a new Unity Project. I did not get the error. I have removed all the models from my current Project and I still receive the error.

Comment: Oooh. Ok, so I don't know what the problem is then. :( Maybe check your import settings on the models? :(

Comment: If I remove them completely there are no import settings to check and I still get the error.

Comment: I've done a little research on this error. People report restarting Unity sometimes fixes it, or installing at a different location. Do you have any spaces in the filepath to the unity editor?

Comment: I do indeed, however I managed to solve the problem by other means.

Comment: So post an answer to your own question, so it helps other people.

Comment: The comment section below my answer suggests otherwise.